# ASP.NET Application Start without using Global.asax

Tags: asp.net, configuration, global-asax

I'm developing a plugin like application for a web site. Due to requirements it will live in the same physical path and the same application pool as the main web site which I do not have the source code for. So they both share the same Web.config and some other dependencies.

I need to set a license for a third party dependency at application start, but I have no way of accessing the code behind for Global.asax as that code is owned by a different company.

So, is there an alternate way of appending events to Application Start without involving Global.asax or is my only solution to inherit/extend the current Global.asax?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a HTTPModule:

```
public class MyModule : IHttpModule
{
    #region IHttpModule Members

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }

    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        ...
    }

    #endregion
}
```

web.config

```
<httpModules>
  <add name="MyModule" type="MyNamespace.MyModule, MyAssembly" />
</httpModules>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use WebActivator if you know your target projects will all be .NET 4.0 or greater.

https://github.com/davidebbo/WebActivator

```
[assembly: WebActivatorEx.PostApplicationStartMethod(typeof(Bootstrapper), "Start")]

public class Bootstrapper
{
    public static void Start()
    {
        // Put everything in motion here
    }
}
```

Note you also have the option of running before or after the Global.asax Application_Start() function - this example runs afterward.